# How to fix the first row not to scroll horizontally

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am having trouble in making a table which has 30 columns but the first row is a header row, so I don't want it to scroll horizontally.
As the table width is too long, I put it in a div and make it scrollable which makes it show only 15 columns at a time.

I can scroll the entire table but don't want to scroll the first row as it is the header row.

See the screenshots:
Table after set position:absolute for first tr
[image: Table before scroll]
Table after scroll without position:absolute
[image: Table after scroll]

Comment: Please provide your HTML and any related code.

Comment: Do you want us to edit your image..?

Comment: @freginold, The code is so messy as it is partly made up with PHP. I just need a simple solution to fix the first row of a table.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri, no I want you to check the images and give some solution to fix it.

Comment: I think I have a good idea, what if you include your HTML and CSS, what do you think?

Comment: I have not yet learnt how to check an image for CSS or HTML. However, jokes apart, if you really want us to help please add your codes along with the question.

Comment: @SachinArtani what you're trying to accomplish is called a "sticky header". If you search on that phrase you'll find there are quite a few questions already on the site which will show various methods for accomplishing this.

Comment: In your case, it would probably be easiest to just take "header" outside of the table and just put it in a div on top of the table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a *id* called *headerRow* and add the following CSS to hide any content from showing even if it is too wide.

```
#headerRow {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Or rather, in this case doing the following:

```
position: absolute;
```

Comment: Please check the improved question. I tried your way but it didn't work.

Comment: You likely added it to the wrong container. I noticed the whole calendar scrolled, try adding it to the larger container or even the body so that the body will not be able to scroll to the side.

Comment: No, I want all the rows to be scrollable except the first one which is the header for the month. The table is in the div element of fixed size and div is allowed to scroll horizontally which is making the entire rows to scroll.

Comment: Try position: absolute; on your header.

Comment: Check new image I upload on question

Comment: Does it stay there? If so then just fix the width so it looks like it did before.

Comment: Hey Jared, I tried doing position: absolute and a little CSS work on the row and columns and it worked!

Comment: The solution is-
Making the row as position:absolute;
Now all the columns inside that row may shrinked but through CSS, we can change width, height, margins and place them accordingly as they will be fix on that position.
Once again Thanks!

Comment: Yeah no problem. I edited my answer so it’s correct, if it answers your question please mark it as the selected correct answer.